# How do I get a Ralink RT3060 wireless card to work?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, ralink

I'm currently running Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit on my desktop. I got Ralink Corp RT3060 ( rt3562sta ) Wireless device. There was no proper support for this driver for ubuntu on their official site. So I have done some patches to install, which can be found [here](http://steveswinsburg.wordpress.com/2011/03/12/how-to-install-a-d-link-dwa-525-wireless-network-card-in-ubuntu-10-04/)

Every hour, I get the following error:

> Panic Mode occurred , switching back to text console.

[image]

Any help?

Comment: What, exactly, did you patch the driver? This could help identify the problem.

Comment: Why are you that sure that the wireless driver is causing the problem? Have you further output in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages? Finally maybe you can do the following instead of rebooting in the console: sudo initctl restart gdm

Comment: I just followed the instructions given on that blog. That's it!

Comment: If I deactivate this wireless driver, then my system will be okay.

Comment: Have you tried using ndiswrapper? I have a similar PCI wi-fi card (D-link DWL520+), which was discontinued 5 years ago, and is working perfectly with ndiswrapper.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,